# tomcat HTTP Status 404 – Not Found after GCP VM upgrade

Tags: java, tomcat, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I did a VM edit on my GCP - stopping and starting the VM after making changes to the machine type etc.
After the change, my tomcat suddenly started giving

curl http://localhost:8080/

<!doctype html>HTTP Status 404 – Not Foundbody {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}

## HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

**Type** Status Report

**Message** Not found

**Description** The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

#### Apache Tomcat/8.5.54 (Debian)

I am not too familiar with tomcat and have tried numerous searches on google and it didnt help.
Starting and stopping the server are working fine

Here are the path variables

/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/shutdown.sh

```
    Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat8/
    
    Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat8/
    
    Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat8//temp
    
    Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64

Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat8//bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat8//bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

my application is at

```
/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/
```

Comment: `CATALINA_BASE` should be `/var/lib/tomcat8` (and it usually is, if you use the `tomcat8` package). Since applications are deployed from `CATALINA_BASE/webapps`, your application will not be deployed if the values you give in the question are true.

Comment: Thank you!! it worked. Please post it as answer so that I can select it. I just set it in my env and restarted tomcat. I guess i should put it in my startup.sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the [File Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) the default directories given by the `tomcat8` package (which I assume you use) are:

```
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat8
CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/tomcat8
CATALINA_TMPDIR=/var/cache/tomcat8
```

Since Tomcat autodeploys all applications in `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps`, you need to set `CATALINA_BASE` to `/var/lib/tomcat8`.

Comment: For some reason, default for me were what I mentioned above i.e. both CATALINE_BASE & CATALINA_HOME were same. I might have changed in the beginning but when I upgraded the VM, GCP might have reinitialized tomcat and it reset the variables again. Might be something basic but it wasted a day for me.

Comment: I think I understand where is the problem: you call `/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/startup.sh` directly, which tries to auto-detect `CATALINA_HOME/CATALINA_BASE`. On Debian 9 you should call `systemctl start tomcat8`, which first sets those variables and then starts Tomcat. You can configure non default values in `/etc/default/tomcat8` (preserved by upgrades), instead of changing files in `/usr/share/tomcat8` (replaced by upgrades).